# Spacing Between Multiple X-Axes in JFreeChart

Tags: graph, charts, jfreechart, spacing

I'm attempting to try and increase the vertical spacing between multiple x-axes using JFreeChart.  Currently, my charts look like this:

[Current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OViXV.png)

However, I need to produce something like the following so that the x-axes are more clearly defined (note that the vertical spacing between the x-axes is larger than in the first image):

[Desired chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxHar.png)

Does any one have any idea on how to do this?  I've been searching the JFreeChart API for > 2 days now and can't find anything that directly addresses the issue other than attempting to use `org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisSpace` in some way.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to customise the axis label insets (that is, increase the space below each axis label).

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setLabelInsets-org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets-

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for your input, David.  I was playing with something like this the other day but can't remember what it was.  This did the job, however  `RectangleInsets familiarisationAxisLabelInsets = familiarisationAxis.getLabelInsets();
    familiarisationAxis.setLabelInsets(new RectangleInsets(
      familiarisationAxisLabelInsets.getTop(),
      familiarisationAxisLabelInsets.getLeft(),
      familiarisationAxisLabelInsets.getBottom() * 5,
      familiarisationAxisLabelInsets.getRight()
    ));`